# C# Unity - Set spring speed of hinge joint upon player collide (novice coder)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I should start by saying I'm a total novice when it comes to both coding and unity but I'm trying really hard to do well in this class so... feel free to give me some guidance.

I've been having issues with this mechanic I'm working on. Basically, I want a bridge to fall over when a player runs into it. I'm trying to accomplish this by using a hinge joint with a box collider, and when the player runs into the bridge the spring speed is set to 10 and the bridge falls into place. However, I keep running into issues with the code:

```
                    using System.Collections;
                    using System.Collections.Generic;
                    using UnityEngine;

                    public class Jointsiguess : MonoBehaviour
                {      
                void Awake()
                {
                   HingeJoint hinge = GetComponent<HingeJoint>();
                  PlayerManager playerManager;
                  JointSpring hingeSpring = hinge.spring;
                   playerManager = FindObjectOfType<PlayerManager>();
                }

                void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
                {
                   if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
                    {
                        hingeSpring.spring = 10;
                        hingeSpring.damper = 0;
                        hingeSpring.targetPosition = 180;
                        hinge.spring = hingeSpring;
                       hinge.useSpring = true;
                    }
                }
            }
```

If you know what I can do to fix this, or if you know of a way I can do this better, let me know.

Comment: Can you give more details about the issues?

Comment: Initally I was getting errors within Visual Studio, but now they show within Unity. However, they boil down to the same thing:

    Assets/Scripts/Jointsiguess.cs(23,28): error CS0103: The name `hingeSpring' does not exist in the current context
    Assets/Scripts/Jointsiguess.cs(23,13): error CS0103: The name `hinge' does not exist in the current context

The same error, several time over

Answer (score 0):

The error message:

> hingeSpring' does not exist in the current context Assets/Scripts/Jointsiguess.cs(23,13): error CS0103: The name hinge' does not exist in the current contex

is due to the variable being local to the awake function. You define the variable locally in the function and it can only be accessed in the awake function.
Instead define the variables in the class like this:

```
                public class Jointsiguess : MonoBehaviour
                {      
HingeJoint hinge;
PlayerManager playerManager;
JointSpring hingeSpring;
                void Awake()
                {
                   hinge = GetComponent<HingeJoint>();
                  hingeSpring = hinge.spring;
                   playerManager = FindObjectOfType<PlayerManager>();
                }
}
```

Make sure when defining variables that you do so globally as C# has scope with its variables. Read more about it here: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpVariableScopes.aspx.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I made the changes, and I no longer get a compiling error, however, my object doesn't register a collision with the player and still refuses to move.

Comment: @TaylorBazhaw I'm not sure what you mean by "still refuses to move", which object needs to move and is this movement player control? Does both objects have a collider and does the player model have a rigidbody?

Comment: @CowNecromancer is right, you need at least one rigidbody to use the Unity's physics.